# Still can't connect internet in emulator 10.0.10166 on VS RC

Tags: c#, wpf

I had trying to "delete all switch on hyper-v and emulator" and disable all connection except internet main.

> Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during
>   bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device
>   '21BE0446-5FB7-415F-9488-4A0D8DE35D16'.': SmartDeviceException - App
>   deployment failed. Please try again.
>
> Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Mobile Emulator 10.0.10166.0 WXGA 4.5
>   inch 1GB' failed. Device cannot be found. App deployment failed.
>   Please try again.